# CakePHP and AppExceptionHandler for not-built in exceptions

Tags: cakephp, exception, cakephp-2.0, http-status-code-503

For exception handling I plan to use this approach

- [Create your own Exception handler with Exception.handler](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/exceptions.html#create-your-own-exception-handler-with-exception-handler)
  or this one:
- [Using a custom renderer with Exception.renderer to handle application exceptions](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/exceptions.html#using-a-custom-renderer-with-exception-renderer-to-handle-application-exceptions)

1) Can you mention about the differences between them? Cookbook tells the difference with this sentence

> "If you don’t want to take control of the exception handling, but want to change how exceptions are rendered..."

2) I'm planning to add **503 Service Unavailable** code as an exception. But How can I implement this error?
Cookbook has such an example for missingWidget, how can I change it for 503 service not available?

```
class AppExceptionRenderer extends ExceptionRenderer {
    public function missingWidget($error) {
        echo 'Oops that widget is missing!';
    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13590614/throwing-a-custom-503-exception-in-cakephp-2

Answer (score 2):

You can use InternalErrorException already available in core.

```
throw new InternalErrorException('Service Unavailable', 503)
```

The error page will be rendered by ExceptionRenderer::error500() method using the view app/View/Errors/error500.ctp. Depending on your needs you can either customize just the view file or make your custom exception renderer which extends ExceptionRenderer and override the error500() method.

Comment: Can you please mention about the two approaches "Create your own Exception handler with Exception.handler" and "Using a custom renderer with Exception.renderer to handle application exceptions" ?? I'm trying to make a decision to use which one of them. Thank you